# Spring for Android Memory issue

Tags: java, android, spring, memory-leaks

I have in a JSON folder on a server about 2000 products. Each one has price,available_sizes and many more entries. For this reason I decide to make an on the fly binding, by using the RESTTemplate class of the Spring for Android framework. This is working perfectly fine. However, I detect with with MAT(Memory Analyzer Tool) that maybe this approach is too heavy for a mobile because detects possible memory leak.

Here there are the Pojo attributes:

```
@JsonProperty
private String brand;
@JsonProperty
private String colours;
@JsonProperty
private String img;
@JsonProperty
private Float GBP;
@JsonProperty
private String name;
@JsonProperty
private String prodnum;
@JsonProperty
private String sizes;
```

However, I don't want to use the

```
   System.gc();
```

and the other related methods because I read that the reduce the performance. Can anyone help and propose me something that could be memory efficient?

Comment: I don't think Spring is the problem; why do you need all 2000 products on the phone when you have a REST service to fetch them for you?

Comment: The concept is that I have to display on the app these products. And then I add these products to the cache in order to make the process faster.

Comment: I understand the concept.  "Faster" isn't working for you if the app crashes.  Follow Rudy's advice below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only load as many item you can display in the device.

Displaying all item is too much, because user may not read them all.

You display 10 ( for example) and upon scroll to the bottom, you display another 10.

To implement something like this, you can use Pagination in List View.

Refer to http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-dynamicaly-load-more-items-to-the-listview-never-ending-list/